# Ajax url not working after deployment

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, url, webforms

I am calling a webmethod from aspx page and it is working fine as per expectation:

```
 $.ajax({
         type: "post",
         url: "MyPage.aspx/GetName",
```

.Cs

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetName()
    {
      ... Some Logic ....
    }
```

> Localhost Url: http://localhost:56286/MyPage.aspx

Now, when I deployed this Url is not working and ajax call is showing error

> URL after deployment: http://localhost:802/MyPage.aspx

What am I doing wrong? I haev tried:

- http://localhost:802//MyPage.aspx//GetName
- ~//MyPage.aspx//GetName

but none of the them worked. Any suggestion?

**Edit**

When I did //myPage.aspx//GetName I got following error in console

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://MyPage.aspx//GetName. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS

I have no idea what it means, but it might help you to understand the issue.

Comment: have you tried `url: "/MyPage.aspx/GetName"`?

Comment: either pass actual url or relative path of the page.

Comment: @Ozgurbar Yes I have tried '/MyPage.aspx/GetName and ~/MyPage.aspx/GetName.'

Comment: @Mukund Do you mean http://localhost:802//MyPage.aspx//GetName or MyPage.aspx/GetName ?? If that so, I have tried it already.

Comment: Try following code,
url: "../MyPage.aspx/GetName",

Comment: @Mukund Tried that too. didn't work !

Comment: Please post code if possible and error description.

Comment: @Mukund Edited my question with the error I got in console

Comment: and what does the err log say when you try to post to `"/MyPage.aspx/GetName"`? edit: ok that's weird; why would it try to post to `http://MyPage.aspx//GetName`? where is the localhost part? can you include the complete ajax function in the question?

Comment: @OzgurBar I am not getting any error on that. When I placed alert on OnError function it is showing poping up 'Error" .. That's it. No detailed error response.

Comment: Please note that you must NOT use double slashes on the URL part, like //MyPage.aspx//GetName, since this will cause the browsers to try to get http://MyPage.aspx//GetName instead. Single slashes are to be used.